# C# dynamically instantiate Type from Enum

Tags: c#, types, enums, instantiation

I am a C# beginner. I hope you have patience with me. Lets say I have an enum

```
public enum Dogs
{
    Terrier,
    Poodle,
    Pitbull,
}
```

and some dog classes

```
public class Terrier {
}

public class Poodle {
}

public class Pitbull {
}
```

And I for some reason want to instantiate each of the classes dynamically from their types (enum values),

```
        foreach(Dogs d in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Dogs)))
        {
            // d myDog = new d();
            // "...is a variable but is used like a type"
        }
```

I have also tried with

```
var myDog = Activator.CreateInstance(d);
// "...cannot convert from namespace.Dogs to System.Type"
```

Comment: While the values in your Enum and your classes have the same names, they are not the same object or Type, which is why your two attempts failed.  Since you are new to C#, I recommend starting with a `switch` statement using the Enum value as the cases, and within each case, manually writing the code that returns the correct type of Dog.  `Activator.Instance` is something usually used when you don't have a direct reference to the Type you want to construct, so I would avoid it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an enum for that. A much saner solution is an array of Types:

```
private static Type[] dogs =
{
    typeof(Terrier),
    typeof(Poodle),
    typeof(Pitbull),
}
```

Then you can still go over them all:

```
foreach (Type type in dogs)
{
    Object dog = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

Though unless you're only using `.ToString()` on it, you might want to give those classes a common interface or superclass to inherit (as rfmodulator also said in his answer) so you can actually call functions on the resulting objects. If all three inherit from a `Dog` superclass, which makes them share a common `Bark()` method, you can at least do something like this:

```
public abstract class Dog
{
    String Bark();
}

public class Terrier : Dog
{
    public override String Bark() { return "Woof!"; }
}

public class Poodle : Dog
{
    public override String Bark() { return "Yap"; }
}

public class Pitbull : Dog
{
    public override String Bark() { return "Whuff!"; }
}
```

...so you can actually get something useful out of your instantiated objects:

```
foreach (Type type in dogs)
{
    Dog dog = (Dog)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    Console.WriteLine(dog.Bark());
}
```

The only slight downside to this method, from a design perspective, is that there's no way to enforce that only sub-types of `Dog` can be put in the `Type[] dogs` array; technically, any type object can be put in there. So that's the programmer's responsibility to not mess that up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Nyerguds, working perfectly!

Comment: I actually use this in a program of mine, for autodetection of file types. It just has the file data read to byte array, and each type tries to interpret it and sees if it matches what it expects, and once a match is found it returns the correct object, with the file loaded in it :)

Answer (score 4):

If you really want it:

```
(typeof(Dogs)).Assembly.CreateInstance(d.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dogs.Terrier` is a different thing than `Terrier`.

Here is how you could do something like you're describing:

For simplicity, I'm going to make all the classes implement a common interface, IDog:

```
public interface IDog { }

public class Terrier : IDog
{
}

public class Poodle : IDog
{
}

public class Pitbull : IDog
{
}
```

Now we can do this:

```
IDog dog;
foreach (Dogs d in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Dogs)))
{
    switch (d)
    {
        case Dogs.Terrier:
            dog = new Terrier();
            break;
        case Dogs.Poodle:
            dog = new Poodle();
            break;
        case Dogs.Pitbull:
            dog = new Pitbull();
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("no such dog!");
    }

    Debug.WriteLine($"dog is {dog.GetType()}");
}
```